# How to customize the "New" button standard page with fewer fields?

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is when clicking "New" button in Opportunity Tab, in the standard page, it shows fewer fields. For example, if you only need to input the Name of the Opportunity, the page only show the Name field.
Point is that it should stay as pop-up, I tried override "New" button with Visualforce page but it is not pop-up anymore.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. please include any code snippets you tried before. so people can help you.

Comment: This link in trailhead might help with over-riding a quick action. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration/javascript_buttons_to_lightning_actions

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirement correctly then I suggest you can go to the page layout of Opportunity SObject and remove all the other fields that are not required without using Visualforce. The procedure is Setup > Object Manager > Opportunity > Page Layout > Oppotunity Layout

Answer (score 0):

Thank y'all.
After one day's struggling, I finally find a solution - to override New Button with a lightning component, which has a modal style and looks like a popup. It kind of solve my problem (although unliking a "action", the background do change after I click the button).
Thank you angain for all the help, I do appreciate.